# Speed up dependency injector compile

Tags: magento2, dependency-injection

Since I have started developing with Magento 2 I've noticed, compiling the dependency injector with `bin/magento setup:di:compile` can take 40 seconds and up to 1 min 20s with xdebug enabled.

I have an Intel i5 CPU M460 2.53GHz running PHP 7.1.11 on Ubuntu 17.10, not using docker or any VM. Is 40 seconds a normal compile time? Is there any way to improve it? It really slows me down when I just need to inject a new object into a class I'm working on and have to recompile everything.

I noticed workload is mostly CPU bound running on a single core. Has any work been done to make it multi-threaded?

I guess I just need to know when a manual `setup:di:compile` would be required when doing development?

Comment: Yes, this is usuall time. Other question - why do you compile your code during development? You don't have to do it.

Comment: I guess you're right. I was working on a class that was complaining about the wrong number of arguments passed to the constructor. Manually compiling the dependencies fixed it so I guess that got me in the habit of doing it. Perhaps it's required for some classes but I don't remember now which class I was working on. Trying now and it is correctly injecting any Interface or class I put in the constructor. Looks like Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer is responsible for doing it. Perhaps I wasn't in developer mode before.

Comment: When you are in developmemt of modules you may want to enable `dev` mode in Magento 2. So, you do not need to `compile` all the time. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-mode.html This artical may help you to do so. `dev` mode slows the application, because it always checks for the changes. However for specific module testing it is good. Once module testing is comoleted, you can `compile` and go for `integration` testing.

Comment: To answer my own question `setup:di:compile` is needed when the object manager is used directly like `\Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
            ->get(\Magento\Framework\EntityManager\MetadataPool::class);` and the parameters for MetadataPool are changed.